# Usb cables marked "CBL"

Tags: usb, printer

What does "CBL" marking on the usb cable stand for?

I was trying to connect printer (HP1020) using standard USB cable (Type A jack to type B jack). The printer didn't work, there was a message about USB Device malfunction. After some troubleshooting I found that the problem is with the cable. Any other cable I tried worked fine, however I found 3 more cables labeled "CBL" and none of them worked with the printer. Does anyone know what's so special about these "CBL" marked cables?

Comment: There's nothing special about them. CBL is just short for "Cable".

Comment: What type of cables were these exactly ( 1.0, 1.1. 2.0, or 3.0 )?  It isn't as simple as the cables being a Type A to Type B cable.

Comment: Unfortunately type of cable isn't specified. It is definitely not 3.0, I can post pictures of the cable if that would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @qasdfdsaq noted, CBL generally stands for cable. CBL is also part of the part number used by one of the larger usb cable manufacturers. In your case the three cables were most likely produced by the same company, and all have the same defect of not working with your printer or possibly at all.

Comment: Yes, it looks like you are right, and there is no special "CBL" marking. Those cables are pretty old so it is possible that they are USB 1.0 or low quality 1.1, and that might be the reason they are not working with the printer.